# retrieve a specific entity descended from a given ancestor in app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, datanucleus

Say I have a book review site, where in my datastore the Book is the ancestor of the Reviews. Given the key-name of a Review, I want to be able to retrieve the specific review without having to retrieve all the other reviews. How might I create a query for that? I looked through [the google site](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries#Java_Ancestor_queries) and have not being able to find an example or recommendation.

P.S. I include data nucleus as a tag because I am open to that approach as well.

Comment: Do you know the ancestor Book as well as the review key_name ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the id or name of the book (whichever you use when creating a key entity), you can construct its key by using KeyFactory.createKey() method. Then you can use the book key and the name of a review to create the key of a review.

With a review key you can simply use data store.get() method to retrieve the review.